# jQuery: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
console.log($('"#'+d+'"'));
```

In my HTML, I have:

```html
<div id="2013-10-23">
    <h1>5</h1>
    <p>eeeeeeeeeeee</p>
</div>
```

In the above code, I have one `<div>` with an `id` of `2013-10-23`, and when getting that `id` it is throwing this syntax error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#2013-10-23"
> ```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try

```
console.log($("#"+d));
```

your solution is passing the double quotes as part of the string.

Answer (score 19):

### The "double quote" + 'single quote' combo is not needed

```
console.log( $('#'+d) ); // single quotes only
console.log( $("#"+d) ); // double quotes only
```

Your selector results like this, which is overkill with the quotes:

```
$('"#abc"') // -> it'll try to find  <div id='"#abc"'>

// In css, this would be the equivalent:
"#abc"{ /* Wrong */ } // instead of:
#abc{ /* Right */ }
```

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen in safari if you try a selector with a missing ], for example

```
$('select[name="something"')
```

but interestingly, this same jquery selector with a missing bracket will work in chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
console.log($("#"+d));
```

This will remove the extra quotes you were using.

Answer (score 6):

Try this (ES5)

```
console.log($("#" +  d));
```

ES6

```
console.log($(`#${d}`));
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to look a little more to solve my problem but what solved it was finding where the error was. [Here](https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression/#:%7E:text=Uncaught%20Error%3A%20Syntax%20error%2C%20unrecognized%20expression%3A%20...,jQuery%202.&text=x%2C%20and%20will%20throw%20an%20Error%20in%20circumstances%20where%20jQuery%201.) It shows how to do that in Jquery's error dump.

In my case `id` was empty and `$("#" + id); produces the error.

It was where I wasn't looking, so that helped pinpoint where the issue was so I could troubleshoot and fix it.

Comment: Thank you for this. It does help us to understand how the structure of the JQUERY error message points to the specific problem location. And indeed - this was the error I was having - I was missing a # id when trying to concatenate values for AJAX i.e. $("#"+Data_G).serialize()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 2.1.4 or above, try this:

```
$("#" + this.d);
```

Or, you can define var before using it. It makes your code simpler.

```
var d = this.d
$("#" + d);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some people coming here, you might have a **special character** in your `id` attribute, so jQuery can't read it correctly.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
> followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
> underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Check this answer for more details:
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#answer-79022)

Answer (score 0):

I had a selector  **with space** (**'#test .test'**).

Example of my error:

```
var href = "javascript:scrollto('"+key+"')";
```

For me this helped: **encodeURIComponent**(value)

```
var href = "javascript:scrollto('"+encodeURIComponent(key)+"')";
```